# Image path from database not displaying-PHP

Tags: php, image, path

Creating a shop page and I'm trying to get the image for the item to display.So In my products database i have products_image that has a path set directly to the image. but it won't display. is there something wrong with my php?

```
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
      extract($row);
      echo "<tr><td>";
      echo "<a href=\"getprod.php?prodid=" . $products_prodnum . "\">";
      echo "<em><img src=\" . $products_image . \"></em></a></td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo "<a href=\"getprod.php?prodid=" . $products_prodnum . "\">";
       echo $products_name;
       echo "</td></a>";
       echo "<td align=\"right\">";
       echo "<a href=\"getprod.php?prodid=" . $products_prodnum . "\">";
       echo "$" . $products_price;
       echo "</a></td><td><a href=\"getprod.php?prodid=" . $products_prodnum . "\">Buy                now!</a></td></tr>";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: everything else works fine. it displays the product name and price. just the image won't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `echo "<em><img src=\" . $products_image . \"></em></a></td>";` to the following:

`echo "<em><img src=\"" . $products_image . "\"></em></a></td>";`

It appears that you are missing a pair of quotations.

Comment: How did i not notice that... Thank you so much. Just needed another pair of eyes

Answer (score -1):

Check your upload path. Also your variable is not coded correctly as you can see it is brown. try the answer above, should work, if not then your path is wrong. If located at root of directory check file is uploaded first and then check why it is not displaying.

for example

```
public function image_path() 
{  
  return $this->upload_dir.DS.$this->filename;
}
```